# Access master page from different folder

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, master-pages

I would think this should be easy
but not sure how to fix.

I have inside Main folder a page named 01.aspx

01.aspx page should inheritance of products.master

Project root existent inside products.master

Like the photo below:

[image]

I use of bellow code but nothing dosent work javascripts,image and ...

01.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Products.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="01.aspx.cs" Inherits="Main_01" %>
```

Products.master

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Products.master.cs" Inherits="Products" %>

<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <%-- product --%>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='js/test/woocommerce-product.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='js/test/style-product.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/test/jquery-migrate-product.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/test/include_scripts-product.js'></script>...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use of ResolveUrl in the src inside master page

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js") %>'></script>
```

Img:

```
<img src='<%= ResolveUrl("images/Logo.png")%>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Page.ResolveClientUrl`

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl('~/js/test/jquery-migrate-product.min.js') %>" ></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src="<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl('~/js/test/include_scripts-product.js') %>" ></script>
```

Another possible solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/ScriptFolder/JSFile.js") %>">
```

Then in Code Behind of Master page under Page_Load Event

```
Page.Header.DataBind();
```

It works for either jQuery and JavaScript as well as CSS just you need to change your path in `ResolveUrl` which file you want to handle CSS, JavaScript, jQuery

Hope this helps !